# Silverlight Toolkit Chart Y-axis label styling

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I am having trouble figuring out how to style the Y-axis labels on a chart (Silverlight Toolkit). Does anyone have a simple example of how to do this? All the examples out in the wild seem to be pre 2010, when the chart API was different.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code that changes the Y-axis to display the labels in hours instead of minutes and changes the font size to 8 (SecondsToHours converter code not included). You can do lots of other kinds of formatting in the Style. This should help you get started.

```
<Style x:Key="HoursLabel" TargetType="{x:Type charting:AxisLabel}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type charting:AxisLabel}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SecondsToHoursConverter}}" FontSize="8" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<charting:Chart.Axes>
    <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Interval="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="24" AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource HoursLabel}" />
</charting:Chart.Axes>
```